# Return a data from async/await axios always return a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My goal is to pass an id from an array to axios in a method and return the result

```
<template>
    <div v-for="person in data">
          <h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
          // Im calling a method, I want to return a data
          <h3>{{ getPersonReviews(person._id) }}</h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     return {
         personData: [{ _id: 3, name: "Donald Trump"}, {_id: 2, name: "Jack"}]

     }

   methods: {
       async getPersonReviews(id) {
           let response = await this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/person-review');
           console.log(response.length) ---> Will return the number eg: 0,2,3
           return response.length ---> Will return [Object promise]

       }

    }

  }

}
</script>
```

For somehow if I `console.log()` it will return the correct data but when I return the data it will return `[Object promise]`. If it is not possible then I will use another solution then.

Comment: Why you fetch a data using http request on for-loop? It's bad. What do you want to achieve? I believe you just need to adjust your API response. You could return it's review counts (maybe) on your person lists API.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function in JavaScript always returns a Promise.

The only way to get the resolved value is to set a value that exists outside of the promise inside of the function:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="person in data">
          <h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
          // Im calling a method, I want to return a data
          <h3>{{ displayValue[person._id] }}</h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     return {
         personData: [{ _id: 3, name: "Donald Trump"}, {_id: 2, name: "Jack"}],
         displayValue: {}
     }
  },
  // trigger data fetch on component load
  mounted() {
      this.personData.map(p => p._id).forEach(this.getPersonReviews);
  },
  // trigger data fetch whenever personData or any of its values change:
  watch: {
      personData: {
          deep: true, // without this, this watcher will only be triggered by 'this.personData = value' statements
          handler() {
              this.personData.map(p => p._id).forEach(this.getPersonReviews);
          }
      }
  },
   methods: {
       async getPersonReviews(id) {
           let response = await this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/person-review');
           console.log(response.length) ---> Will return the number eg: 0,2,3
           this.displayValue[id] = response.length;

       }

    }

  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where do I trigger the method?

Comment: `mounted() { this.personData.map(person => person._id).forEach(getPersonReviews); }`

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer to take into account array values.

Comment: I should put the mounted() ? because I already did v-for on the template. So doing another array loop is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your answer still havent solve the triggering part.

Comment: Typically, you don't want to display the return value of a function within a template either way, because it will only get triggered on re-render and forcing a re-render can be tricky in Vue. (And you'd still need a deep watcher if you want to force that re-render appropriately)

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated the answer to handle triggering the data fetch.